# Could not find profile: TwoOrgsChannel in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I want to get genesis.block,but Could not find profile:  TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis.I can't get channel.tx as the same reason.

```
[myg@Ubuntu e2e_cli]$>../../build/bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
2018-03-23 11:33:24.235 CST [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2018-03-23 11:33:24.335 CST [common/tools/configtxgen/localconfig] Load -> CRIT 002 Could not find profile:  TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis
2018-03-23 11:33:24.335 CST [common/tools/configtxgen] func1 -> CRIT 003 Could not find profile: TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis
panic: Could not find profile: TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis [recovered]
    panic: Could not find profile: TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/op/go-logging.(*Logger).Panic(0xc42021a090, 0xc42026c770, 0x1, 0x1)
    /home/myg/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/op/go-logging/logger.go:188 +0xbd
main.main.func1()
    /home/myg/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen/main.go:242 +0x115
panic(0xc3db80, 0xc42026c760)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:505 +0x229
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/op/go-logging.(*Logger).Panic(0xc4201b1ec0, 0xc420240560, 0x2, 0x2)
    /home/myg/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/op/go-logging/logger.go:188 +0xbd
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen/localconfig.Load(0x7ffee2bcf0c8, 0x15, 0x0)
    /home/myg/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen/localconfig/config.go:248 +0x7b4
main.main()
    /home/myg/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen/main.go:250 +0x4d2
```

Comment: did you solve the problem?